# proving of the given conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures

let us suppose that there is given  such  kind of conjecture
[image]

if  their division is  square of integer  then we  will have

$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=k^2$

for some  integer $k$, then  we would have

$a^2+b^2=k^2*ab+k^2$

or  we would have

$a^2-k^2*a*b+b^2=k^2$

compare  to the equation

$a^2-2*a*b+b^2=(a-b)^2$

we would have

$k^2=2$

but is that proof ? i could   not understand  if there is  another option  or alternative ways

Comment: ahaa thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your reasoning was correct, then you would have proven that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is *not* the square of an integer, since you end up with $k^2 = 2$ for some integer $k$, which is a contradiction.

But, you make a mistake when you 'compare'

$a^2-k^2*a*b+b^2=k^2$

with

$a^2-2*a*b+b^2=(a-b)^2$

and conclude $k^2=2$ to make these equations match.  But why should these equations have to match?  Yes, if $k^2 = (a-b)^2$ then we can conclude $k^2 = 2$, but why should we believe that $k^2=(a-b)^2$?  There is nothing in our givens that would say that ... all we know is that $k^2$ is *some* square.  (in fact, we know it *cannot* be $(a-b)^2$, for then we obtain $k^2=2$, i.e. a contradiction!)

More importantly, though, what you have to prove is that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is *always* a square once we know that $ab+1|a^2+b^2$. So, *assuming* it is a square is assuming exactly what you need to prove, and is at best giving you confirmation that it *could* be a square, and at worst giving you some kind of circular argument.